# Bayes' theorem in a medical context

Tags: bayesian, medicine

Imagine an essentially random, very large population of people (say 50 million individuals).

A given subset of them have a disease 'D'.

By inspecting this subset, we observe that 40% of the people in it are female (F), 90% have elevated blood pressure (B), and 70% have a history of neck trauma (N).

In the overall population, the prevalence of the above characteristics is: 50% F, 30% B, 15% N.

If $P(D)$ is the probability of having disease 'D' in the overall population, $P(X)$ is the probability of having a characteristic 'X' in the overall population, $P(D|X)$ is the probability of having disease 'D' within the subset of people that have characteristic 'X', and $P(X|D)$ is the probability of having characteristic 'X' within the subset of people that have disease 'D', I think Bayes' theorem can be rearranged to tell us that:

$\frac {P(D|X)} {P(D)} = \frac {P(X|D)} {P(X)}$

If so, in the above example we might conclude that:

$\frac {P(D|F)} {P(D)} = \frac {P(F|D)} {P(F)} = \frac {40%} {50%} = 0.8$

$\frac {P(D|B)} {P(D)} = \frac {P(B|D)} {P(B)} = \frac {90%} {30%} = 3$

$\frac {P(D|N)} {P(D)} = \frac {P(N|D)} {P(N)} = \frac {70%} {15%} = 4.67$

In other words, if you're a female you're slightly less likely than the general population to have the disease; if you have elevated blood pressure you're 3-fold as likely; if you have a history of neck trauma you are almost 5-fold as likely.

First question: is the above reasoning correct?

Second question: if so, is this just an observation applying to the specific population under study, telling us nothing about the probability of *future* diagnoses of 'D'? Or can we use this knowledge to make predictions, e.g. can we reasonably predict that a male with elevated blood pressure and history of neck trauma is more likely to be diagnosed with 'D' than a female with normal blood pressure and no history of neck trauma?

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185817/interpretation-of-bayes-theorem-applied-to-positive-mammography-results

Comment: Thank you @Tim , I had already seen that post and I am familiar with the concept of PPV vs TPR. I don't really see how it answers my questions, though. In the post, the prior probability of the disease is always known, the probability of a positive test is calculated based on it, and further probabilities are calculated (e.g. the PPV). In my case, the question is whether we can make predictions about *odds* (i.e. ratios of probabilities). Are people with elevated blood pressure 3-fold as likely to have disease 'D', compared to the general population, even when they haven't yet been diagnosed?