# Combining predictions with errors

Tags: mathematical-statistics, prediction, combinatorics

If i were to try to combine two predictions, such as:

Test 1:  $70\% \pm 10\%$ sure that $x$ is between $1.5$ and $2.5$
Test 2:  $65\% \pm 10\%$ sure that $x$ is between $1.5$ and $2.5$

combination of test $1$ and two find $XX\% \pm YY\%$ sure that $x$ is between $1.5$ and $2.5$.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that 1.5 and 2.5 appear in both cases, or is that indeed the general intention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining probabilities/information from different sources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155817/combining-probabilities-information-from-different-sources)

Comment: the range is intentionally consistent, I am comfortable with how I will combine the ranges if they vary, it's how to accurately combine the percentages with uncertainties I can't do. 

running two tests and getting the same result should, in theory, make you more confident and reduce the error, I think?

Comment: Hi @Tim, I have read the question you have referenced there and think this is a different situation. This has an associated error, which I cannot figure out how to carry through. 
I also don't think the confidence would be 67.5%, because running the second test and getting the same result should increase how confidently I can state that x lies between 1.5 and 2.5. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered this as a meta-analysis problem? I may have misunderstood your intentions though.

Comment: It isn't clear to me that this is a duplicate. But I think it would help if you explained what "70% plus or minus 10% sure that $x$ is between 1.5 and 2.5" means - this isn't the usual way that confidence intervals are written for example. What does the "plus or minus 10%" refer to?

Comment: Thanks Silverfish, I understand this is an odd format.  If you had someone very confident telling you they were 70% sure someone was perfectly healthy, but knew they had an unreliability due to a lack of information of approximately 10 percent. This Is a simplified version of events of course, but I have been told a system is approximately 70 percent accurate, with an uncertainty in the accuracy of 10%

Comment: Forgive me if that's still unclear, it's hard to explain properly without getting stuck into the details

Comment: You can if it makes the problem easier, swap the range of 1.5 to 2.5 to an integer value, as I can get a confidence In an integer too

Comment: Has anyone got any thoughts on this?