# Is it possible to combine predictions to improve overall prediction quality?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, boosting

This is a binary classification problem.  The metric that is being minimised is the log loss ( or cross entropy ).  I also have an accuracy number, just for my information.  It is a large, very balanced data set. Very naive prediction techniques get about 50% accuracy and 0.693 log loss.  The best I've been able to scrape out is 52.5% accuracy and 0.6915 log loss.  Since we are trying to minimize the log loss, we always get a set of probabilities ( `predict_proba` functions in sklearn and keras ). Thats all background, now the question.

Lets say I can use 2 different techniques to create 2 different sets of predictions that have comparable accuracy and log loss metrics.  For example, I can use 2 different groups of the input features to produce 2 sets of predictions that are both about 52% accurate with < 0.692 log loss.  The point is that both sets of predictions show there is some predictive power.  Another example is that I could use logistic regression to produce one set of predictions and a neural net to produce the other.

Here are the first 10 for each set, for example:

```
p1 = [0.49121362 0.52067905 0.50230295 0.49511673 0.52009695 0.49394751 0.48676686 0.50084939 0.48693237 0.49564188 ...]
p2 = [0.4833959  0.49700296 0.50484381 0.49122147 0.52754993 0.51766402 0.48326918 0.50432501 0.48721228 0.48949306 ...]
```

**I'm thinking that there should be a way to combine the 2 sets of predictions into one, to increase the overall predictive power.  Is there?**

I had started trying some things.  For example I consider the absolute value of the prediction minus 0.5 ( `abs( p - 0.5 )` ) as a signal, and whichever between `p1` and `p2` had a greater signal, I would use that value.  This slightly accomplished that I wanted, but just by a slim margin.  And in another instance it didn't seem to help at all.  Interestingly it didn't seem to destroy the predictive power.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/155817/35989

Comment: The numbers you give for p1 and p2 are all pretty close to .5, you log loss is very close to ln(2), and an accuracy of 50% is the same as flipping a coin. These are terrible results, and it's unlikely that you will get significant improvement with stacking. You should be looking at other techniques such as feature engineering.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you doing sports match predictions or market prediction of some sort?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: This is one of many examples of a technique known as "stacking". While you can, of course, decide on some manual way to combine both predictions, it is even better if you train a third model on the output of the first two models (or even more). This will further improve the accuracy. To avoid re-using the data, often a different part of the data set is used for training the first levels, and training the model that combines the data.

See e.g. [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/stacking-models-for-improved-predictions-a-case-study-for-housing) for an example.

Comment: This is exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. 
The method you are talking about is called Stacking. It is a type of ensembling method.  In this method, in the first stage multiple models are trained and the predictions are stored as features which will be used to train the second stage model. A lot of Kagglers use this method. Generally, you should use more than 2 models for the first stage while stacking (I generally use at least 4-5 models). There are also many methods in which stacking can be performed like simple averaging, majority voting etc. Here is a link to a kaggle kernel which implements stacking on the famous Titanic Dataset which is also a binary classification problem. 
[Kaggle Kernel Intro to Stacking using Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/arthurtok/introduction-to-ensembling-stacking-in-python)

Comment: Note that often you can use the same *type* of model, but using different parameters. Random forest, for instance, is basically a stacking method with decision trees as the base models.

Comment: Side note. My way of thinking about ensembling methods using averaging and majority voting, iirc, is that they reduce the variance of predictions. Ie, they smooth the prediction surface.